# Trouble: Despicable Me Edition-Why is the 1 red?

Tags: trouble-despicable-me

My family got a brand new copy of [Trouble: Despicable Me Edition](http://www.hasbro.com/en-us/product/trouble-game-despicable-me-edition:0FE66F20-5056-9047-F53E-A59988130B96). We were wondering why the 1 on the regular die was red, when the only special roll is 6.

Comment: Are the dice special in any other way (e.g. images on the sides)? Hasbro may just be using the same dice they use for most of their games to keep costs down, and their dice happen to have the bigger red pip on the 1 side (many six-sided dice embellish either the 1 or the 6 in some fashion, and I think 1 is more common).

Comment: @ConMan No. That's the only thing.

Comment: My money is on them being generic Hasbro dice then.

Answer (score 1):

Dice produced in Asia usually have the one, and sometimes also the four coloured in red. I've heard a variety of reasons including superstition (no sillier than numbering the 13th room 12A), Emperor's decree or that in some traditional Asian dice games these are special numbers.
The real reason these days is probably just that they have always done it that way.
Regardless, you can probably assume that this dice was sourced from Asia or intended for the Asian market.

Comment: Do you have any evidence that this also applies to american games? From what I am reading there is no reason that this would apply to Sorry which is not a game with Asian roots as far as I am aware.

Comment: While the game might be American, I think you will find most of Hasbro's production is in China. This is true for most of these companies. There are links about this on the Hasbro wikipedia page.
While this might not be the most patriotic answer, I think you will find this is probably the most likely answer, so I'm not sure the down vote is warranted. Do you have a better explanation?

Comment: I am not sure what your point is, I would wager that most games are made in China but they do not have special colors for their dice. The point was that the game and all of its components are designed based on where they are sold not where they are manufactured. And if you had evidence that Hasbro is doing things different because of customs in China then you should have provided the links and evidence. My response was based on there being no evidence to back it up or reason why an American children's game would be based on influences from China or the Asia region in general.

Comment: I'm not sure what I've said to upset you so I apologise if I have.
My point is that Asian dice have red ones, this game was produced in China, and so that is the most likely reason since there is nothing in the game design to suggest 1 has a special meaning. I agree games should be designed for their intended market but I doubt a game as generic as Trouble was going to have a designed or specified dice. In the absence of a better answer I think this is the most likely answer.

Comment: You answered this question with no evidence to support your answer, when questioned about it your reasoning that was because it was made in China. Well the simple fact that is a lot of products are made in China/Asia in general and they don't have any design influences from China/Asia in them because they are not being marketed over there which goes to show that just because it may be made in China doesn't mean that it has any influence over the design of the game itself.

Answer (score -1):

In our game of Trouble, rolling a 1 meant that the other players could bring a piece out of home but it doesn't affect the player that rolled.

Comment: As far as I understand, you're describing a houserule. Is that the case?

Comment: I gave the same answer a few months ago and it was downvoted.

Answer (score -1):

The rule that Nina mentions above and Mike R references (red 1 is special for having others move a peg out of home) is not a house rule. That is printed in the instructions I got with the game opened from Christmas this year. I do not see that referenced in the posted rules from the Hasbro site, but I've got it in print from a fresh box.

Comment: Can you please confirm you are referring to the Despicable Me edition? It looks like the previous answers you reference were downvoted and/or deleted because they refer only to classic Trouble, which does not answer the question.